# TCPDF align header

Tags: php, tcpdf

This is first time im using TCPDF , very good library but im not sure how to align `SetHeaderData` with my design

[image]

Here is my code :

```
define ('PDF_HEADER_STRING', "No. A-3-2, Kompleks Industri Puchong, No.1 Jalan TPP 1/6, Taman Perindustrian Puchong Seksyen 1, 47100 Puchong, Selangor Darul Ehsan, Malaysia.\nTel: (603) 8068 6119    Fax: (603) 8051 8119    Website: www.projectormalaysia.com\n\nQuotation No: ".$quo_quotationNo."          Date: ".$_POST['date']);

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('AV Tech Solution Sdn Bhd');
$pdf->SetTitle('PDF Quotation');
$pdf->SetSubject('PDF Quotation');
$pdf->SetKeywords('');
$pdf->SetHeaderData('avs-logo.png', '30', 'AV Tech Solution Sdn. Bhd. (958788-U)'.' ', PDF_HEADER_STRING);
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array('times', '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$tagvs = array('p' => array(0 => array('h' => 0.5, 'n' => 0.5), 1 => array('h' => 0.5, 'n' => 0.5)), 'br' => array(0 => array('h' => 1, 'n' => 1), 1 => array('h' => 1, 'n' => 1)));
$pdf->setHtmlVSpace($tagvs);
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
$pdf->AddPage();
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what is the desired alignment you need ?

Comment: the alignment should follow with image after...

Comment: This thing doesnt work in today's date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem when my custom header was extremely small and not at all where I wanted it to be.

It should be in one of the examples on the TCPDF website, [Custom Header and Footer](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_003.phps)

Just follow that and you should (hopefully) have no problem.. that is if you're still trying to work that out haha.

It basically says you need to write a new function Header() to override the existing properties of the default header.

Hope this helped, and good luck.